# Add data frames to a list and re-run a loop in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop over a data frame inside of a list. I run several operations inside the loop and build a new data frame that I add to the list. I want after that, that the loop takes this new data frame that I add to the list and re-run the operations with this new data frame. I want to perform this several times, but I do not know how to do it. My current code looks like the following:

```
list_r <- list(Original=df)
i <- 1

for (i in seq_along(list_r)){
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(5,5))
list_r[[i+1]] <- df2
i <- i+1
}
```

This is a simplification of my code, but someone could explain to me why my loop does not run again when I add a data frame into the list? (re-run again the code but now for df2)

Comment: The bounds of the for loop, `seq_along(list_r)`, is computed when the loop starts. It isn't recomputed every time. And for loops in R auto-increment, `i <- i + 1` is usually wrong inside a `for` loop. Instead, I think you want a `while` loop. Something like `while(i <= length(list_r)) {... i <- i + 1}`. Just make something happens as some point to end the loop...

Comment: The i <- 1 doesn't do anything so it can be removed.  list near the bottom of the loop should be list_r .  df2 does not change from one iteration to the next so should be removed from the loop  and placed before the loop to avoid needlessly redefining it over and over again even though it has not changed.